# Time zones and Calendars in iOS

Tags: ios, timezone, reminders

I am trying to create a to do list app for iphone with reminders.
However, I am a little confused about how to handle various time zones and calendars ?
Say I am in timezone A and set a reminder to go off in 5 hours.
And if move to a different Time zone B , will iOS automatically take care of triggering the reminder after a time interval of 5 hours ?

Comment: Good luck on this.  I've had no end of grief dealing with weird timezone issues on a big calendar app.  Don't forget to take Daylight savings time into consideration too.  Always a pain for me!

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not shift the reminder timing if you do not adjust it, assuming you are using UILocalNotification as an example, with the fire date is NSDate instance.

From NSDate class reference:

> NSDate objects represent a single point in time.

A single point in time stays the same even if you move between different timezones.

Comment: Exactly!  A point in time is a point in time.  Otherwise, traveling between time zones would literally be time travel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on whether you have Timezone Support enabled on your iOS device.  Apple provided a good article right here, which I think helps answer your question: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4576

Specifically:

> Time Zone Support will allow you to create and view events in a time zone other than the one currently used by your iOS device (other than the one your clock is set to). If you do not use Time Zone Support, your iOS device will default to the current clock setting. iOS devices that are location aware will automatically set their time zone, date, and time using Location Services.

There was also a similar question asked on Apple Stackexchange here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63232/calendar-mac-iphone-timezone-support-question.  Specifically the answer here:

> Events created whilst time-zone support is off default to the native time-zone of the calendar which was set when it was created and turning time-zone support off lets the iPhone automatically shift the times of appointments to the local time.

So with "time-zone support" disabled, it should allow the device to adjust based on your changing time zone.